# How do I find out the dimensions of some text

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com

I want to pass to a dll call some text and the font details (eg. font, size)

I want to retrieve the width and height of the text in pixels

It must be in a dll, as it is being called from Classic ASP

I'm aware there are things like TextMetrics, but don't know how to go about wrapping this in a COM object.

How do I do this (in C# please)?

Comment: If this is for Classic ASP then I presume that this is for a website?  If so then this will depend on other things (like the browser zoom and whether or not the desired font is available on the client)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you can use Graphics.MeasureString.

Pass the text and the font, as a System.Drawing.Font object.
The method returns a System.Drawing.SizeF object.

Hope it helps.

Bye!

Sorry, edited: (ok..huge one)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MeasureSize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var size = GetTextSize("This is a test!", "Arial", 10, "normal", "bold");

            Console.Write("Width: {0} / Heigth: {1}", size);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static object[] GetTextSize(object value, object fontFamily, object size, object style, object weight)
        {
            if (value == null || fontFamily == null || size == null) { return new object[0]; }

            var result = new object[2];
            var text = value.ToString();
            var font = default(Font);
            var composedStyle = string.Concat(style ?? "normal", "+", weight ?? "normal").ToLowerInvariant();
            var fontStyle = default(FontStyle);

            switch (composedStyle)
            {
                case "normal+normal": fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Regular; break;
                case "normal+bold": fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Bold; break;
                case "italic+normal": fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Regular; break;
                case "italic+bold": fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold; break;
            }

            font = new Font(fontFamily.ToString(), Convert.ToSingle(size), fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            using (var image = new Bitmap(1, 1))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                var sizeF = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);

                result[0] = Math.Round((decimal)sizeF.Width, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
                result[1] = Math.Round((decimal)sizeF.Height, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work. Graphics doesn't have static method MeasureString. You have to specify variable of type Graphics

Comment: The line: return System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font); is giving me an error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: @Graham try my approach or mix these. I told about this error before ur comment

Answer (score 1):

May be smth like that (works in ASP)

```
public static SizeF MeasureString(string s, Font font)
{
    SizeF result;
    using (var image = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            result = g.MeasureString(s, font);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This one has no errors - so will use it as a starting point - thanks

Answer (score 0):

These msdn links should provde you with what you are looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx